# Issue in recursive function in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

My recursive function is

```
private dynamic FillRecursive(List<AllAccounts> flatObjects, Guid accountID)
{
    List<AllAccounts> recursiveObjects = new List<AllAccounts>();

    foreach (var item in flatObjects.Where(x => x.ParentID.Equals(accountID)))
    {
        recursiveObjects.Add(new AllAccounts
            {
                AccountID = item.AccountID ,                
                Children = FillRecursive(flatObjects, item.AccountID)
            });
    }

    return recursiveObjects;
}
```

When I send request to this function from postman it stops the running program in Visual Studio Code. Kindly help me resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Why is this function `dynamic`?

Comment: When would you expect this to stop recursing?

Comment: I expect to stop when all elements of list itterated.

Comment: Set a breakpoint.. step through your code.. inspect the variables and the flow.. see whats going on.

Comment: ... and there should be some kind of error message / exception. Note that if there are objects like "a.ParentID = b, b..ParentId = a" you'll have an infinite loop. Sometimes using `Debug.WriteLine` can help understanding such issues.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do _in words_? Can you then describe what `FillRecursive` is supposed to do _in words_?  You're asking us to determine what your intent is from broken code and it would be easier for us if you just tell us straight up what you're trying to do rather than have us guess from your code.

Comment: Are you trying to produce a flat list of all descendants of an account?

Comment: He's iterating over a flat list of accounts and creates a new list of accounts where each account has a property `Children` filled with accounts (from flat list) where `ParentID` equals current `AccountId`. Note that each child account may have children too.

Comment: Please do not post a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61548654/982149) of this question. If you want to improve it, you can [edit] it.

Answer (score 0):

Test if this work

```
private dynamic FillRecursive(List<AllAccounts> flatObjects, Guid accountID,  List<AllAccounts> recursiveObjects=null)
{
    if(recursiveObjects==null)
       recursiveObjects = new List<AllAccounts>();

    foreach (var item in flatObjects.Where(x => x.ParentID.Equals(accountID)))
    {
        recursiveObjects.Add(new AllAccounts
            {
                AccountID = item.AccountID ,                
                Children = FillRecursive(flatObjects, item.AccountID,recursiveObjects)
            });
    }

    return recursiveObjects;
}
```